# Testing a Static Methods Class had to be Changed to a Singleton For JUnit Testing

Tags: java, android, static, junit, singleton

I have a static methods class, Utils, that is basically for utility methods, its used by almost every class.  It does things like get files and other basic stuff.  My tester went and changed this class to a singleton so that every class using Utils now has to call getInstance().  The reason was that he couldn't test certain things unless this was the case.  It seems to me that this is wrong in some ways and that this could lead to issues.

```
public class Utils {

/**
 * Singleton method to allow for easier testing.
 * @return an instance of
 */
public synchronized static Utils getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Utils();
    }
    return instance;
}

public synchronized static void setInstance(Utils instance) {
    Utils.instance = instance;
}

/** Singleton to make testing easier **/
private static Utils instance = null;

public static boolean checkOSTen() {
    return getInstance()._checkOSTen();
}

private boolean _checkOSTen() {
    boolean autoPair = false;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){   
        autoPair = true;
    }
    return autoPair;
}

}
```

By the way I have a very complex system of internal messaging that uses at least 7 threads to send messages and wanted to see if there is an impact of static method calls vs Singleton static method calls.

Is there another way to do testing other than this?  Seems some Java reflection would get what you need.

Comment: i dont know the answer on your main qustion, but the better way to implement `singleton` is `double checking method` if you use few threads in your app.

Comment: Can you add an answer with this double check method example?

Comment: it will be better then my own answer: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Apparently this will cause problems later on in the article it states "The bottom line is that double-checked locking, in whatever form, should not be used because you cannot guarantee that it will work on any JVM implementation. JSR-133 is addressing issues regarding the memory model, however, double-checked locking will not be supported by the new memory model. Therefore, you have two options:
    Accept the synchronization of a getInstance() method as shown in Listing 2.

    Forgo synchronization and use a static field.
"

Comment: @JPM That article is from 2002. Apparently JDK5 has fixed this issue, if you use the `volatile` keyword: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tester probably finds this code difficult to test as they can't easily change the return value of `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, and therefore they can't easily test the different code paths that are used depending on this return value. By using an instance method they can use a mocking framework to fake the `_checkOSTen` method to return either `true` or `false`, depending on what they are trying to test.

Another way to do testing is to not use static methods such as these at all, and instead use class (perhaps called `DeviceCapabilities`) which will be injected via a setter or a constructor into every other class that requires knowledge of the version of the OS.

Then, your tester could easily pass instances of `DeviceCapabilities` to whichever class needed access to this information.

That said, at this stage in your build it may be too late to make a change like this so the change your tester has made is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: What impact does changing it from static methods to Singleton instance used across 9 different threads?  Will this code cause it to use more/less memory now?  Will the synchronizing bottle neck calls across threads?

Comment: I would expect any increase in memory usage to be insignificant. The use of `synchronize` could cause it to be a bottleneck, but this is entirely dependent on how often each of your threads calls `getInstance`. The only way to know for sure is to profile the code. However, switching to a dependency injection style via a `DeviceCapabilities` class should eliminate the risk of this bottleneck, as no `synchronize` will be required.